Use Beautiful Soup to count Title/Links
I am attempting to write a code that keeps track of the text for the links in the left handed gray box on this webpage. In this case the code should return
Valykrie, The
Acid Baby
Here is the code I am trying to use:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll('a', class_= 'new-indicator'):
    print(link)

It is not working (otherwise I wouldn't be here!) I'm pretty new to BeautifulSoup, and coding in general. No matter how much I inspect the page source I can't seem to figure out the inputs to the findAll to get it to return what I want!

Try [a.text for a in soup.select("#left-nav-route-table a")]

can you elaborate on this answer?

Search for the table with a specific I’d, than the rows:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id']=="left-nav-route-table") 
rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='a')

for member in rows:
    print(member.text)

Output:
Acid Baby
Valkyrie, The

If you would also see the href link add
print(member.get('href'))


All the values are stored in the table tag with id="left-nav-route-table" as href form.
Photo of the table
Sample code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel"

resp = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,'lxml')
data = soup.find('table', id="left-nav-route-table") #locate the table with the help of id
#this table has two href values each containing your desired output as text form so I used .text.strip() func, but they're in unserialized format so I printed [1] value first and [0] second to match Your condition
print(f"{data.findAll('a', href=True)[1].text.strip()}\n{data.findAll('a', href=True)[0].text.strip()}")

Or
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel"

resp = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,'lxml')
text = soup.select("#left-nav-route-table a")
print(f"{text[1].text}\n{text[0].text}")

Output:
Valkyrie, The
Acid Baby


After reviewing the source code of the website you provided, I guess you want to extract text from the following two tags:
<a href="https://www.mountainproject.com/route/111083885/the-valkyrie" previewlistener="true">Valkyrie, The</a>
<a href="https://www.mountainproject.com/route/109928434/acid-baby" previewlistener="true">Acid Baby</a>

so you can't use the 'class_' param. So you should use the ID of the outer table tag:
url = 'https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find('table', id='left-nav-route-table').find_all('a'):
    print(link.get_text())


Always check if the HTTP GET has succeeded. Use lxml for optimised HTML parsing if available. Use CSS selectors in preference to XPATH - again, for better performance.
# use lxml if available for better HTML parsing performance
try:
    import lxml
    PARSER = "lxml"
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    PARSER = "html.parser"

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

URL = "https://www.mountainproject.com/area/109928429/aasgard-sentinel"
SELECTOR = "#left-nav-route-table a"

with requests.get(URL) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BS(response.text, PARSER)
    print(*map(lambda e: e.text, soup.select(SELECTOR)), sep="\n")

Output:
Acid Baby
Valkyrie, The

